# In Oracle/SQL how to select rows where the value of the columns remained the same

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

In Oracle/SQL how to select rows where the value of the columns remained the same

I have a list of budget, each budget spread over 12 months, with fixed salary each month. I would like to return a list of budgets for which the value of the salary remained the same over 12 months.

```
BUDGET MONTH SALARY
5468 1              1500
5468 2              1500
5468 3              1500
5468 4              1500
5468 5              1500
5468 6              1500
5468 7              1500
5468 8              1500
5468 9              1500
5468 10             1500
5468 11             1500
5468 12             1500

3456 1              1675
3456 2              1675
3456 3              1675
3456 4              1675
3456 5              1500
3456 6              1500
3456 7              1500
3456 8              1500
3456 9              1675
3456 10             1675
3456 11             1675
3456 12             1675

3948 1              2900
3948 2              2900
3948 3              2900
3948 4              2900
3948 5              2900
3948 6              2900
3948 7              2900
3948 8              2900
3948 9              2900
3948 10             2900
3948 11             2900
3948 12             2900

9756 1              2900
9756 2              2900
9756 3              2900
9756 4              2900
9756 5              2900
9756 6              2900
9756 7              2900
9756 8              2900
9756 9              2900
9756 10             2900
9756 11             2900
9756 12             2900

9712 1              2743
9712 2              2900
9712 3              2900
9712 4              2900
9712 5              2743
9712 6              2900
9712 7              2743
9712 8              2900
9712 9              2900
9712 10             2743
9712 11             2900

5394 1              1500
5394 2              1500
5394 3              1500
5394 4              1500
5394 5              1500
5394 6              1500
5394 7              1500
5394 8              1500
5394 9              1500
5394 10             1500
5394 11             1500
5394 12             1500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count the `distinct` salary for every budget

```
select budget
from your_table
group by budget
having count(distinct salary) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT BUDGET,SALARY FROM BUDTGET_TAB
HAVING COUNT(MONTH)=12
GROUP BY BUDGET,SALARY
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: I have posted this answer as in the above given answer if the months are less(suppose 8 are there only for some budget) and salary remain same till that month and can't say whether it will remain same for the remaining months so the result could fail here and also here in above question it is asked to find the same salary for the budget over the year(12 months).

Comment: please specify the reason for down vote as i did it practically, then answered it .

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT BUDGET,SALARY FROM BUDTGET_TAB
GROUP BY BUDGET,SALARY
HAVING COUNT(MONTH)=12
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

I have just rearranged the query which was written by Dharmesh ...

Comment: yes one can opt for both way by writing having before group by or after group by, would produce the same result ...